# Contact Form Not Sending

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

I'm trying to set up a simple contact form. Everything is styled correctly, but when I hit submit it doesn't take me anywhere, just attempts to open contact.php. I think there's something missing in the code that actually sends the message out. I'm sure it's something fairly simple that I'm missing, but this is a little over my head. Any help is appreciated.

```
<form action="mail.php" method="POST">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Company</p> <input type="text" name="company">
    <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
    <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "______@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

$to ='______@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've received your information"

if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>
```

EDIT: I was able to receive an email finally after adding the complete url for mail.php...however none of the information except for the message was included. The sender was listed as Apache...how can I assure that information entered in the forms will be included in the email? Thanks for all the help thus far.

Comment: Does it try to open contact.php or mail.php? Make sure PHP is running properly on your server.

Comment: It tries to open mail.php. I'm able to see the information and styles from my other PHP files on my page (before I click submit) if that answers your question.

Comment: Check your permission for mail.php - try 755, try 777. Also go to mail.php directly and see what happens. Can you post mail.php's content here?

Comment: The content from mail.php is the PHP from my first post.

Comment: ok so it is posting it to itself. try putting in a phpinfo() in there and see if it renders. If not, it is a your web server/permissions related problem.

Comment: Thanks for your input, fkim. After screwing around a bit and including the entire url for mail.php I was able to receive an email...however non of the information was included except for the message and it was from "Apache".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are specifying code within the same page, you can omit `action` in your form.
Also, put a condition to run PHP once the script has been run.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "______@gmail.com";
$subject = "Contact Form";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";

$to ='______@gmail.com';
$send_contact=mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);

// Check, if message sent to your email 
// display message "We've received your information"

if($send_contact){
echo "We've received your contact information";
}
else {
echo "ERROR";
} }
?>
<form action = "<?= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>"method="POST">
    <p>Name</p> <input type="text" name="name">
    <p>Company</p> <input type="text" name="company">
    <p>Email</p> <input type="text" name="email">
    <p>Phone</p> <input type="text" name="phone">
    <p>Message</p><textarea name="message" rows="4" cols="25"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT: I am not sure what is the current filename but to keep it dynamic, I have mentioned `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` which is not a recommended usage.
However, Try it! :)

Comment: Thank you for helping. Unfortunately I just got a 404 message after hitting submit (I entered my own email address in place of the line, of course). Is it possibly because it isn't linking to my mail.php any longer?

Comment: Karma, thanks. Instead of the PHP I simply used my mail.php and included a direct link...I think that might have been the hold up all along. However I now have a new problem....

I just received the email, however it is stating that it is from "Apache" and lists none of the information except for the message in the email. How can I make sure all of the necessary information is included?

Comment: I think it can work without $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] on same page with using POST method only

Comment: for that open up a new Question and close this. If the answer helped you then accept it